# Google Tag Manager Variable - Custom <a> attribute value

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i have a slider which the link code looks like this:

`<a href="#" gtm-class="item-1"><img></a>`

I want to pass the click custom attribute value to a variable in gtm.

This using custom js doesent work:

```
function () {
var el = {{Click Element}}, gtmDataEvent = el.getAttribute('gtm-class');
return gtmDataEvent;
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML looks incorrect. What is `<img>`? Is that an image tag? With the real code, when you click on it, your click element may be referencing the image, and not the anchor. You'll have to check and test for that. If that's the case, then you would need to do something like:

```
function () {
   var el = {{Click Element}}, gtmDataEvent = el.closest('a').getAttribute('gtm-class');
   return gtmDataEvent;
}
```